# flask-admin: revise the button text

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I haven't found similar questions on stackoverflow, I'd like to change the **save** button to **submit** or **confirm** on the **edit form**. I know this might not be easily changed. Thanks for any advise in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After search in the code of `flask-admin`, I found the button is rendered with macro `render_form`, `render_form_buttons`, `extra`. The value of these buttons is hard code with `{{ _gettext("blabla") }}`.

As these buttons are not fields of data model, we can't use [rendering rules](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/#customising-builtin-forms-via-rendering-rules) to custom the value. I think there are two work arounds to get this done:

- change the macro which render these buttons in the source of `flask-admin`(`render_form_buttons`, `extra`)
- `flask-admin` use `flask-babelex` to do localization(`{{ _gettext("blabla") }}`), you can 'translate' `Save` to `submit` or `confirm` with flask-babelex

UPDATE:

You can custom `edit.html` in your own template directory.

```
{% extends 'admin/model/edit.html' %}
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import extra with context %}
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import form_tag with context %}
{% from 'admin/lib.html' import render_form_fields with context %}

{% macro my_render_form_buttons(cancel_url, extra=None, is_modal=False) %}
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 submit-row">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ _gettext('Submit') }}" />
            {% if extra %}
            {{ extra }}
            {% endif %}
            {% if cancel_url %}
                <a href="{{ cancel_url }}" class="btn btn-danger" role="button" {% if is_modal %}data-dismiss="modal"{% endif %}>{{ _gettext('Cancel') }}</a>
            {% endif %}
         </div>
    </div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro my_render_from(form, cancel_url, extra=None, form_opts=None, action=None, is_modal=False) -%}
    {% call form_tag(action=action) %}
        {{ render_form_fields(form, form_opts=form_opts) }}
        {{ my_render_form_buttons(cancel_url, extra, is_modal) }}
    {% endcall %}
{% endmacro %}

{% block edit_form %}
    {{ my_render_form(form, return_url, extra(), form_opts) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @ stamaimer, thanks,  but it did not work after revising the `edit.html` in my **templates **folder.

Comment: Have you ever set `edit_template = path_to_your_custom_edit_template` in the model view?

Comment: do you mean this: `edit_template = 'edit.html'` which is in the  `class CustomView(ModelView)` of my `app.py`?

Comment: Follow [this](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#adding-your-own-views)